# Convex polytope — from vertices to faces

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-geometry, polytopes, discrete-geometry, convex-hulls

Suppose I have the vertices of a convex hull. How can I find inequalities of the form $A x \le b$ that form the convex hull?

For simplicity, consider the convex hull in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: check out these slides on the V-representation and the H-representation: http://www.ece.drexel.edu/walsh/JayantCHM.pdf

Comment: @LinAlg Are there any applicable codes available regarding those slides?

Comment: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/7895-vert2con-vertices-to-constraints

Comment: How is this not a duplicate of [this other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3216041/339790)?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Cause the problem is totally stated in different literature. People who refer to the problem might find different ways of explaining it.