# Converting convex hull from $V$-representation to $H$-representation

Tags: algorithms, computational-geometry, polytopes, discrete-geometry, convex-hulls

After looking at many articles and understanding various algorithms regarding finding extreme points and convex hull of a set of vectors in $\mathbb{R}^d$, I still have not figured out how to go from vertex representation of a polytope (specifically convex hull) to a half-space representation of it. I also know that it is called facet enumeration of some sort in the literature. I am looking for simple article discussing the exact problem I have already stated which is $$V\rightarrow H$$
I have a set of extreme points of a convex hull and I want to find the halfspace-representation of it. Any simple code, by simple of course I mean a program targetting the exact problem rather than being part of a bigger project like [Qhull](http://qhull.org/html/qhull.htm), would be really appreciated.

I have already read [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1299959/characterize-polytopes-resulting-from-cutting-a-convex-polytope-by-a-hyperplane) and referred to references provided there but still none of them discussed anything regarding $V$-representation to $H$-representation conversion. Probably I have overlooked, I do appreciate if anyone has found anything anyways.

Comment: Have you seen the [paper about the Quickhull algorithm](https://www.cise.ufl.edu/~ungor/courses/fall06/papers/QuickHull.pdf)? Not sure it’s exactly what you want but they do describe the idea

Comment: @DavidM. I've read the paper. It does not address my question unless I am missing something!

Comment: A generic method to obtain the $H$-representation is to use the Fourier-Motzkin elimination: Let $V$ be a $(d \times n)$-matrix whose columns are a set of vectors. The convex hull of these vectors is given by the set $\{\mathbb x \mid \exists \mathbb u:  \mathbb u\geq \mathbb 0, \mathbb{1}^T\mathbb u=1, \mathbb x = V\mathbb u\}$. Eliminating all coefficients $u_1,\dots,u_n$ of $\mathbb u$ from the system of linear inequalities by Fourier-Motzkin yields an $H$-representation. But this method is not efficient and the resulting $H$-representation will contain redundant constraints.

Comment: @WillemHagemann Is there any resource explaining this method completely?

Comment: The Fourier-Motzkin elimination should be found in almost any textbook on polytopes (Ziegler: Lecture on Polytopes) or linear prgramming (e.g. Matousek, Gärtner: Understanding and using Linear Programming). The system of linear inequalities is easily obtained by formalizing convex combination of vertices.

Comment: Be warned again: The elimination method is mainly of theoretical interest. For any non-trivial example the number of resulting linear inequalities will explode.

Comment: @WillemHagemann I welcome any working and understandable method available.