# How to find a set of linear inequalities from the vertices of a $d$-dimensional convex polytope?

Tags: euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry, linear-programming, polytopes, discrete-geometry

Let $S = \{x_0, \dots, x_n\} \subseteq (\mathbb{R}^+)^{d}$ be the set of vertices of a convex $d$-dimensional convex polytope ($d \geq 2$).

I am interested in finding a set of linear inequalities such that a point $x$ is inside the polytope iff $x$ satisfies all the inequalities. I have seen discussions about the converse problem (find vertices from the set of constraints), but not this one. The context is to use those inequalities as constraints in a linear program.

Comment: Isn't this the [facet enumeration problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_polytope#Construction_of_representations)?

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3216041/339790)

Comment: Oh yes, thank you very much, I didn't know it was this problem.
Have a nice day !